# How to Cube Root in xcode?

Tags: iphone, xcode

I've been trying to make a specific calculation in xcode with user defined variables. Here's what I have:

```
-(IBAction)calculate:(id)sender{
    NSString *oneField = self.one.text;
    NSString *twoField = self.two.text;
    double resultInNum;
    double onedouble = [oneField doubleValue];
    double twodouble = [twoField doubleValue];
```

And what I need to do, is cube root the outcome of

```
(twodouble/onedouble)
```

I can't quite find away. Any ideas?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use the `pow` function from `math.h`

```
pow(x, 1.0/3.0)
```

Comment: Any reason I can't find the Math framework when trying to add it from the library?

Comment: Got it, had to add the Foundation framework and then call in Math.h in the implementation file. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

## Swift

Swift has cubic root functions built in. Here are the signatures:

`public func cbrt(_: Double) -> Double
 public func cbrtf(_: Float) -> Float`

The definitions are located in `Darwin` module on OS X and `Glibc` module on Linux.

Answer (score 2):

Include `math.h` and call `pow()`:

```
 pow(twodouble/onedouble,1.0/3);
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't remember if math comes included but if it doesn't:

```
#import <math.h>
```

Then:

```
pow(twodouble/onedouble,1.0/3.0);
```

Taking something to 1/n is like taking the nth root. 1/3 is taking the cube root, 1/2 is taking the square root, etc.

Answer (score -1):

Just raise the divided value to the power of 0.33 ?

```
NSLog(@"%.f", pow(result,0.33) );
```

Comment: Careful, 0.33 is merely a rough approximation of 1/3. So, you should not use 0.33, or you may lose a lot of needed precision. At the very least exaggerate and do 0.33333333333333333333333333333 so as to define a constant that goes beyond the limits of what a Double can carry and let the compiler truncate it.